# Add a tab to SlidingTabLayout dynamically (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I followed these [guidelines](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) to create a Sliding tab layout with fragments. The problem is that I want to dynamically add a tab to the SlidingTabLayout. The following code creates a fragment but it isn't displayed. How can i attach it to the SlidingTabLayout?

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tableFragment = (ReportTableFragment) adapter.getItem(1);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.pager, tableFragment, tableFragment.getClass().getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This is my ViewPagerAdapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        //ReportMapFragment reportMapTab = new ReportMapFragment();
        //return reportMapTab;
        SupportMapFragment mapTab = new SupportMapFragment();
        return mapTab;
    }
    else
    {
        return ReportTableFragment.newInstance(1);
    }

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty easy :)
You should add this methods to your 'ViewPagerAdapter' and change the CharSequence by this

```
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now the constructor should be:

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> mTitles, int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.titles = mTitles;
    this.numbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
}
```

Methods to add to the 'ViewPagerAdapter':

```
public void addTab (String title) {
    this.titles.add(title);
    this.numbOfTabs++;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteTab (int position) {
    this.titles.remove(position);
    this.numbOfTabs--;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And from your activity or wherever you call the SlidingTabLayout:

```
this.mAdapter.addTab("NewTab"); // add a new tab
this.mAdapter.deleteTab(0); // or delete a current tab
this.mTabs.setViewPager(this.mPager); // don't forget this line, is the key
```

Pay attention to the 'getItem' method in your 'ViewPagerAdapter' cause now you are adding tabs dynamically ;)

I.